# What's the correct way to reference elements in an array?

Tags: solidity, truffle, dapp-development, tutorials

I'm going through the [Ethereum Pet Shop Truffle tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) and found this in the test section:

`address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);`

A previous section had used `adopters[petId] = msg.sender;`

Why does one use `[]` and the other `()`?

Comment: It's a Solidity language feature - it generates getters for public storage variables, including arrays and mappings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial says that,

`address[16] public adopters;` is a public state variable. Therefore, according to the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters),

> The compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public
>   state variables.

What you are seeing here: `address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);` is the tutorial accessing the automatically generated getter for the public `adopters` state variable.

Here is a simple example I created, to explain this for you:

[image]

Put this in the [Solidity online compiler](https://remix.ethereum.org) to see the outputs are as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Where you see the square brackets, an array element is being accessed from within the same contract. This is a direct read or write to the array.

Where you see the curved brackets, it's usually a function call, most commonly made from outside the contract.

If an array is marked `public`, the compiler automatically creates an accessor function that takes the index you're calling as a parameter. This is what's happening with `adoption.adopters(8)`; The `adoption` contract has a function called `adopters`, which is the equivalent of:

```
function adopters(uint idx) public constant {
    return adopters[idx];
}
```

You also occasionally see curved brackets with an array in a different context, where it is being used to initialize an in-memory array of a particular length. The following will create an in-memory array of 8 addresses:

```
address[] memory adopters = new address[](8);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `()` is a function call.

In the tutorial, you'll see that the adopters array is `public`:

```
address[16] public adopters;
```

In Solidity, all public attributes of a contract [automatically result in a getter with the same name being created](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#getter-functions); that is what you are seeing being called.